# could install flutter apk in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, apk, apktool, avd-manager

I am trying to install and run apk file in android emulator.After installed,Application is not running.

Here is information:

1.Pixel5_API_28

> **E/FlutterLoader: Flutter initialization failed.**
> at io.flutter.embedding.engine.h.c.d(Unknown Source:23)
> at io.flutter.embedding.engine.b.(Unknown Source:184)
> at io.flutter.embedding.engine.b.(Unknown Source:12)
> at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.F(Unknown Source:106)
> at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.n(Unknown Source:7)
> at io.flutter.embedding.android.i.J0(Unknown Source:10)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.o1(Unknown Source:49)
> at androidx.fragment.app.u.c(Unknown Source:199)
> at androidx.fragment.app.u.m(Unknown Source:124)
> at androidx.fragment.app.n.d0(Unknown Source:277)
> at androidx.fragment.app.n.b1(Unknown Source:84)
> at androidx.fragment.app.n.a0(Unknown Source:21)
> at androidx.fragment.app.n.S(Unknown Source:42)
> at androidx.fragment.app.n.y(Unknown Source:11)
> at androidx.fragment.app.i.c(Unknown Source:4)
> at androidx.fragment.app.e.onStart(Unknown Source:15)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1432)
> at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7848)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)

Comment: Do you find any issue on `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: Maybe i' wrong. i have not developed this application. I just want to install extracted apk.

Comment: I have fixed some issues that are showing in flutter doctor -v. Now error is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a Native Code or any changes in the **android** folder, then try to delete the **android** folder and run the following command in the terminal:

`flutter create .`

Comment: I just want to install extracted apk files. Does it matter to install flutter?

Comment: No I don't think it is related to the Flutter installation, I think it is project based issue

Comment: I have fixed some issues that are showing in flutter doctor -v. Now error is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found

Comment: Then the problem is related to Flutter installation, I suggest you to delete the installed flutter stuff and do a fresh installation according to the steps in the official documentation.

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install